# search and echo results of subfolders with forfiles

Tags: cmd

I need some assistance with getting the forfiles cmd to produce a result for subfolders/ files .

I can get 
forfiles /s >>f.csv 
to display a list of all files/folders and subfolders but I cannot get the properties I require when adding the remainder of the /c cmd

forfiles /s /c "cmd /s /c echo @fname,@ext,@relpath,@fdate  >> f.csv

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran it on my PC and noticed that perhaps you left out the closing double quote? `"`

```
forfiles /s /c "cmd /s /c echo @fname,@ext,@relpath,@fdate" >> f.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben! Thought there was something minor missing, its working perfectly now.